# Converting svg to png using imagemagick 6.5.4, text not displayed on the resulting png

Tags: imagemagick-convert

I am new to the whole SVG and imagemagick, so still learning things as I go.  I have this image in a svg format, which I would like to convert to png.  This is how the SVG looks like when opened using Chrome:

[image]

The original SVG file also has some white spaces, which I would like to trim out.  After doing some searching, I found out the "trim" option that can be used in "convert".

I tried the following:

`convert -trim example_image.svg example_image.png`

Which seems to trim out any unnecessary white spaces and most of the SVG file is converted.  However, the text portion of this image is no longer visible in the png file:

[image]

I went through some forums and most of them seems to suggest to start by checking the DELEGATES section that I can read using "convert -list configure", and look out for tags such as "freetype" and "gs".  So it seems like those two tags are available.  Is there anything else I could do to diagnose the issue?  I don't necessarily generate these SVG files (it is generated by one of the colleagues at work), so not sure where to look exactly.  However, I am attaching a snippet of the SVG "code" that prints the text portion.  I hope this might help somebody diagnose the issue:

```
<g transform="translate(0, 480)">
    <g transform="translate(50.000000, 0)">
        <switch x="0" y="0">
            <foreignObject height="300" requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility" width="1150">
                <p style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Figure 1. Putative Fusion-translocation event. The 5&apos; (in the fusion) transcript EWSR1-001(ENST00000397938) from the gene EWSR1(ENSG00000182944) on the forward strand is drawn top left with its corresponding breakpoint at 22:29684366. The 3&apos; (in the fusion) transcript FLI1-004(ENST00000525560) from the gene FLI1(ENSG00000151702) on the forward strand is drawn top right with its corresponding breakpoint at 11:128664210. Exons are drawn to scale relative to other exons in the same drawing. Introns are scaled to make up approximately  1/4th of the final drawing. This is predicted to be an IN-frame fusion. Domains include: </p>
                <div style="display: table; font-family: Arial; font-size: 20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                    <div style="display: table-row; font-family: Arial; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                        <div style="display: table-cell" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Domain Name</div>
                        <div style="display: table-cell; padding-left: 20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">External identifier(s)</div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="display: table-row; font-family: Arial; font-size: 20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                        <div style="display: table-cell; font-family: Arial; font-size: 20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Ets</div>
                        <div style="display: table-cell; font-family: Arial; font-size: 20px; padding-left: 20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">PF00178</div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="display: table-row; font-family: Arial; font-size: 20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                        <div style="display: table-cell; font-family: Arial; font-size: 20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">RRM_dom</div>
                        <div style="display: table-cell; font-family: Arial; font-size: 20px; padding-left: 20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">PF00076</div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="display: table-row; font-family: Arial; font-size: 20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                        <div style="display: table-cell; font-family: Arial; font-size: 20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Znf_RanBP2</div>
                        <div style="display: table-cell; font-family: Arial; font-size: 20px; padding-left: 20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">PF00641</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </foreignObject>
        </switch>
    </g>
```

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to upgrade your ImageMagick as it is now on v6.9 so you are 3-4 years behind the curve...

Comment: Actually, v6.5.4 is from 2009 - a lot has changed.

Comment: Hi Mark,  sorry for the late response.  I was out of town for week.  Thanks for your reply.  I will try to get it upgraded.

Comment: Actually, just out of curiously, what are some of the noticeable features with this version of imagemagick, compared to the old version that we have?  I would like to know, if there is anything other than upgrading the version, which need to be done to solve the aforementioned issue.